# Jaydebeapi giving error in python for CharConversionException

Tags: python, db2, jpype, jaydebeapi

Getting CharConversionException in python Jaydebeapi when trying to pull data ? Not sure where how to set db2.jcc.charsetDecoderEncoder property in python to resolve this.

Exact error - com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlException: com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlException: [jcc][t4][1065][12306][4.25.13] Caught java.io.CharConversionException.  See attached Throwable for details. ERRORCODE=-4220, SQLSTATE=null

Please help in setting charsetDecoderEncoder property in python. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which exact jre/jdk are you using?

Comment: java version "14.0.1"

Answer (score 0):

Since you've tagged this with WebSphere, I assume you're trying to use wsadmin to invoke a jython script, if so do something like `wsadmin -D<propName>=<propValue> -f myJythonScript.py`.

Comment: then just add the -D part to the command line where you invoke the python script.

Comment: This did not helped.

Comment: python script.py -D db2.jcc.charsetDecoderEncoder=3